# How could robots learn the new language of the human?

Tags: language, artificial-intelligence

There is a community of androids living in the ruins of Fresno after the apocalypse. They trade with the local humans for fusion batteries which they need for power. It is essential that they are able to talk to the humans for trade purposes, but there is one problem. The robots are programmed to speak only 3 languages, modern day English, modern day Spanish, and modern day French. But, the humans language eventually becomes a descendant of the modern day languages we speak today, and 500 years after the apocalypse, it’s unintelligible to anyone who speaks any modern language today. So, my question is, what plausible explanation could I give for how the robots could speak to the humans?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding Talos 6! Oh, wait, is it you again? Well, you may find the [help],[meta], and [tour] useful anyway. You might also want to use [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions), though I think a newer Sandbox should be posted soon. Have fun!

Comment: Hey guys, it happened again. I tried registering and that didn’t work. I don’t know what to do

Comment: This is your call. If robots can learn, they will. If robots are no better than Siri, they will stumble. But people of Fresno may speak archaic language just to be able to trade with these creatures.

Comment: @Talos6, if you have a Google or Facebook account I think you can log in automatically:  that's what I do since I have Gmail. Shame you can't ask for help in [chat]/[meta].

Comment: If your premise is that robots can't learn (which I think is implied, otherwise this is trivial), it's up to the humans, isn't it? Either they construct devices to talk to them or they learn modern day French (or whatever). There might be a lot of scholars studying English because of the huge cultural influence it had for some period in history, they might love to get their hands on those androids. Imagine the amount of people that would love to speak real Latin and that's much older than 500 years

Comment: @Raditz_35: I mean, by which method could they go about learning the new language

Comment: @Alexander: No, even when they try to speak the archaic language, the words aren’t very clear and so words have been given the wrong meanings.

Comment: @Talos6 How did they learn English in the first place? The same exact method

Comment: @Raditz_35: They we’re programmed with it before they were “Born”

Comment: @Talos 6 - if humans lived there all 500 years, they will preserve the knowledge. But if they pop up in the area after a long while, this of course will be difficult.

Comment: @Alexander: Yeah, in the first 70 years they just got most of their batteries form a factory that made them, but that eventually ran dry. They hadn’t interacted with the humans at all verbally.

Comment: @Talos 6 if robots are bad learners, but otherwise are as intelligent as humans, they can communicate using pictures and gestures.

Comment: @Alexander: Trading requires abstract concepts, nothing that could be explained with gestures.

Comment: @Talos 6 your robots are not capable of understanding abstract concepts, and trading in particular?

Comment: @Alexander:No, I mean they won’t be able to gesture abstract concepts and give them names

Comment: @Talos 6 they don't need to give any names - just to express the concept through pointing to different objects. If I (a human) go to a different country, I can make a simple trade with locals despite neither of us speaking common language.

Answer (score 5):

*Hey, Talos!  There must be something about your phone's browser that's getting in the way of the registration process.  I seriously suggest connecting with a friend with a laptop and using it to create an account.  I'm even going to suggest that you hold off more questions until you get this done.  There's simply too many!  Once you have an account, you can post to the SE folks and give them a list of your previous monikers and they can round it all up and stuff it into the new account.*

---

**Now, back to our regularly scheduled programming**

This problem has already been solved, you just need to remind the reader of that fact.

The human mind is amazing at only a handful of things, one of which is *pattern matching.*  We can pick a deer out of the landscape on a mountainside at 70mph while listening to Def Leppard and hear our baby crying from across a crowded room.

Machines, on the other hand, have had a harder time of it.  That's because *each and every human* has a different "dialect" of language.  Language is high-pitch to low-pitch, squeeky to growly, fast to slow ... and don't even mention our nasty habit of stressing the *wrong syllable.*  The human mind is simply adept at overcoming most of this very easily (I still have a wee bit o' trouble with rual Scottish).

Honestly, people need to be *thoroughly trained* to professionally and correctly speak "modern English."

- In the beginning was [really bad speech synthesis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3QV_2hq8qU&feature=youtu.be&t=30s).
- Then came really bad voice recognition that [hasn't improved much today](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=My40XgYEvLM) (BTW, it was SHEER LUCK that the youtube example I found was a Scot!).
- But, the technology has improved and with it the ability to recognize people's voices.

And your androids would have had to have that software, or they would have been stuck with literally every human who approached them with a different voice pattern.

**Conclusion**

Since your androids already have the ability to associate new sound patterns with existing references to come up with the correct meaning, all they need is time.  With every deteriorated word they successfully map to the original language they begin to see patterns in language drift (which is what they were programmed to accomodate anyway).

And not too long after that they're speaking Portu-Greek with the best of them!

*BTW, humans [still have trouble with voice recognition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ziS0SnA2tU&feature=youtu.be&t=1m20s), just to make a point.*

Comment: Yeah, I’m gonna try to registering on a different device

Answer (score 3):

Organic speech changes over time.  If the androids were programmed to be able to track and adapt to variations in speech, which they almost certainly would be, this is a non-issue.  The androids are capable of learning new slang and dialectical variations at least as fast as teenagers.

The critical thinking and decision making involved with making deals is actually considerably more complicated.  I would expect it MUCH more likely the androids would succumb to charlatans and predatory exchange rates LONG before they were challenged by shifting languages.

Comment: predatory exchange rates. Oh no, if you don’t trade fairly with the androids, they just kill you, take what they want, and blame it on the nearest pack of raiders

Comment: Determining "fairness" and executing corporal punishment of those offenses is a WAY HIGHER level of sophistication than speaking in modernized pidgen.  I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: They don’t determine anything. They just have a set price, and if you go over it your terminated.

Comment: @Talos6 Market fluctuates. Their "set price" could easily become unprofitable for the humans, in which case they just wouldn't trade. What would the androids do then?

Comment: @Galastel: It’s aids the prices

Comment: @Talos6 Your last comment isn't a sentence.  ??

Comment: @Talos6: imho it's way too difficult to justify the trade with such a not-actually-trading-but-killing-instead androids, than to justify that they can learn the new language over time. Are your androids moved by artificial intelligence or are more like a bunch of scripts?

Comment: Also (somehow didn't notice it) "blame it on the nearest pack of raiders" is a whole NEW level of complex AI... seriously, language is your smallest hurdle.

Answer (score 2):

**The humans maintain an ambassador.** (@Alexander)

The robots have have something to trade that the humans want. If the robots can't speak a contemporary human language some humans will learn enough robot language to get the point across. It might not need to be a whole language.

**Trade doesn't require much language**

Many animals with zero mutually ineligible words conduct some kind of trade with humans. Offering goods and demanding payment can be physically communicated.

If the robots are powerful enough that no humans have wiped them out for their scrap value, they might simply accost prospective trade partners, steal what they want and give what they would trade. Humans who thought it was a good deal would bring more of what was stolen and take steps to minimize friction in the exchange.

**Robots are user friendly**

They have a helpful user manual with pictures and demo videos. It could even include descriptions of the kinds of things they might like to trade for.

**Robots are hackable.**

They have a big file called strings_eng.txt on their harddrive containing everything they can say. Someone changes it so they are more clearly distinct to contemporary ears. As messages are figured out from context they can be replaced with local versions.